# How to select last li in ul including the il element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="offers-list row">
  <li class="column large-3 offers-image" name="orden-1">
    <a title="Title" href="my-ofer-link">
        <img src="my-image-src" border="0">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQyery, I'm trying to select the **li** element like this:

```
$('.offers-list.row li').last()  // I use last because I have more than one
```

And I want to get the full **li** element, so I tried this:

```
$('.offers-list.row li').last().html()
```

But then it only shows the content of the **li** element. Like this:

```
"<a title="Title" href="my-ofer-link">
    <img src="my-image-src" border="0">
</a>"
```

How can I also get the **li** element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.outerHTML` with dom object of returned element

```
$('.offers-list.row li').last()[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly :)